# An increasing number of patients...(has or have?)

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

This is taken from an exercise book, but I don't quite get it why the answer is ''**have**'' on this.

> An increasing number of patients seem to be dissatisfied with conventional medicine and has/**have** turned to alternative therapies.

Which one is the subject here, the ''**an increasing number**'' or the ''**patients**''?

Comment: Your question might get flagged because of the similarity to questions posted on EL&U, specifically [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/59753/a-number-of-students-vs-the-number-of-students) and [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5378/a-number-of-questions-has-been-or-have-been-asked). You may find those helpful.

Comment: I've read both of those links, they are not the same as mine -due to conjugations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters, "have " matches with "seem".  If you use the plural conjugation with one verb, you have to use it with both.

More significantly, the subject of the verbs is not "number" but rather "number of patients".  *Numbers* can't be dissatisfied with their medical care, only *people* can.  It's a plural collective.  Consider this similar example:

> Many children **are** playing outdoors today.

In the same way "an increasing number" is simply a quantifier that tells us *how many* patients feel this way.  However, we could rewrite the sentence as:

> The number of patients (who are) dissatisfied with conventional medicine **is** increasing.

Comment: @ScottM  True.  I've edited to clarify.